# I want to build a small data analysis dashboard, is my approach correct?

Tags: python, stack, dashboard

I'm building a small side project on the analysis of the sentiment of public companies' shares and I want to expose my thought process so that you can criticize it and suggest possible improvements.

The idea of the project is to practice several skills to improve my daily job (I work for a data startup in Italy)

The idea for the project is:

fetch news headlines on a dailybasis with a scheduled Python job, with https://newsapi.org/ (example : $AAPL stock related headlines)

preprocess them with Python and SKlearn, applying the "pipeline" practices, to clean and preprocess the data

build a NoSQL database with all the processed data (I can fetch only since last month with the APIs, so with time I want to build my local headlines history

for the DB I was thinking about MongoDB or ElasticSearch, some suggestions here?

analyze sentiment of the headlines, and save them in the DB

after this collection-cleaning-analysis process, I will use Dash https://plotly.com/dash/ to build an interactive dashboard with the results (then host the dashboard with Heroku)

Better MongoDB or Elastic for my use case? I don't think I really need the Elastic scalability, but I've seen some cool features that MongoDB doesn't have.

What do you think of the architecture? Can I do better with some tools / libraries I didn't mention

Comment: This is too broad for an SO post. Typically a post is a single question on troubleshooting a singular problem. Critiquing every aspect of your approach is too broad.

Comment: Ok, do you have a suggestion about MongoDB vs Elastic search?